# Storing data in two CSV strings vs two db tables for fastest comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

The scenario is that we have two lists:

A: 23,45,g5,33

B: 11,12,45,g9

We want the fastest mechanism in SQL SERVER to see if any of the values from B is available in A, in this example 45 is in A so it must return true.

The solution should describe the way to store the lists (CSV, tables etc.) and the comparison mechanism.

Each list is relatively small (average 10 values in each) but the comparison is being made many many times (very few writes, many many reads)

Comment: volume? Indexed tables should be the fastest

Comment: Two lists? You mean two columns? How about store them in the SAME column with an ID for what you are splitting it off of. You haven't stated if this data is in SQL Server already. However, don't ever store values as comma separated string in SQL Server, generally speaking. You're going to have to split it anyway for comparison.

Comment: @scsimon the data itself is two list but it could be implemented as two columns or two tables or whatever, for example two csv string columns or two tables that are being compared with except

Comment: @Horaciux Lists are relatively small and each contains 10 values max but they are being compared millions of times

Comment: Odd question if you are asking to store it in different tables versus the same table and different columns. The same table would be faster, but this isn't the question to ask when designing a database usually, it's the relationships and normalization

Comment: @scsimon you mean splitting and double loop comparison on same table is faster that storing on two tables and comparing with except?

Comment: The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. Describe your real scenario, not your approach to solve it

Comment: You almost should never loop in SQL Server. With that being said, I agree with @Horaciux that this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that needs clarification

Comment: I'm shooting in the dark with the little data about the real problem, but, if you really need speed in determining a match, and you have time at insertion time, I'd maintain a table with pre calculated matches via a trigger.

Comment: Updated the question to be more clear

Comment: Plain and simple. Stop storing delimited data like this. It violates 1NF and makes queries a LOT harder and slower.

Comment: Agree with @SeanLange. With that being said, test some solutions below in your environment. See what's fastest

Answer (score 0):

I'm still confused as to the core idea... but here is a simple solution that's better than a comma separated list. Creating indexes would make it faster, of course. It's far quicker than looping.

```
declare @table table (id char(4), v varchar(256))
insert into @table
values
('A','23'),
('A','45'),
('A','g5'),
('A','33'),
('B','11'),
('B','12'),
('B','45'),
('B','g9')


select distinct
    base.v
    --,base.*
    --,compare.*
from 
    @table base
inner join
    @table compare
    on compare.v = base.v
    and compare.id <> base.id
```

**Split Way**

```
declare @table table (id char(4), v varchar(256))
insert into @table
values
('A','23,45,g5,33'),
('B','11,12,45,g9')

;with cte as(
    select 
        t.ID
        ,base.Item
    from 
        @table t
        cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.v,',') base)

select
    t.Item
from
    cte t
inner join
    cte x on 
    x.Item = t.Item
    and x.id <> t.id
where
    t.id = 'A'
```

**[USING THIS FUNCTION](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K] (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!

RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN

/* "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)*/

  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with the delimited string, consider the following:

**Example:**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ColA] varchar(50),[ColB] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('23,45,g5,33' ,'11,12,45,g9')
,('no,match'    ,'found,here')


Select * 
 from @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Match=IsNull(sum(1),0)
                 From  [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](ColA,',') B1
                 Join  [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](ColB,',') B2 on B1.RetVal=B2.RetVal
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ColA          ColB          Match
23,45,g5,33   11,12,45,g9   1
no,match      found,here    0
```

The UDF if Interested

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

Comment: Nice, but is it faster than @scsimon answer?

Comment: @mohas Hard to say.  Still not 100% clear.  Are you looking for any match in any string?  If so, I have an alternative

Comment: @mohas If nothing else, the Parse Function provided is one of the fastest methods

Comment: Yes, please share

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer, I think it should look like this:

```
declare @table table (id char(4), v varchar(256))
insert into @table
values
('A','23'),
('A','45'),
('A','g5'),
('A','33'),
('B','11'),
('B','12'),
('B','45'),
('B','g9')


if exists( select count(1)
        from 
            @table base
        inner join
            @table compare
            on compare.v = base.v
            and base.id='A' and compare.id='B') 
 print 'true'
 else
 print 'false'
```

index on id, v or v, id depending on grow of your data